# How to install Evernote SDK for c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, evernote

I'm a newbie in using Visual C++. Currently i'm developing a project for my university that is supposed to work with Evernote API. I've searched the web for the tutorials and guides about installing Evernote SDK for Visual C++ , but i haven't found anything useful yet. Maybe anyone is exprienced in using Evernote API for C++ and can tell me how to install it and start using it? I will be very grateful

Comment: From the [Evernote Developer Documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/): [Install SDK](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows) and [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/Getting_Started.md).